# How to check if a connection between a server and an app is encrypted?

Tags: tls

I have a Corona SDK sample project that contains only the following code:

```
-- The following sample code contacts Google's encrypted search over SSL
-- and prints the response (in this case, the HTML source of the home page)
-- to the Corona terminal.

local function networkListener( event )

    if ( event.isError ) then
        print( "Network error: ", event.response )
    else
        print ( "RESPONSE: " .. event.response )
    end
end

-- Access Google over SSL:
network.request( "https://encrypted.google.com", "GET", networkListener )
```

The code has been copied [directly from Corona SDK's documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/network/request.html#httpsssl).

Once the network request completes, the console will output the requested HTML source. However, **my question is, how can I verify that the network request and all information that was exchanged was actually encrypted and not clearly legible as it is in the console output**?

I am planning on creating an app that will communicate with a PHP file on my server over SSL and being able to verify that the traffic between the server and the Corona made app is actually encrypted is essential since I'd be sending over passwords and other confidential (but not personally identifiable) information.

Comment: I'm not quite clear what your concern is. If you are communicating over HTTPS then it will be encrypted.... What else do you need to check?

Comment: I want to verify that it is being encrypted. I don't want to assume that just because the network request is in https that it impossible for the data not to be encrypted. If the certificate doesn't work or one side doesn't correctly handle it, then it would fail, and I want to ensure that this doesn't happen.

Comment: @ConorMancone actually it is possible to use TLS without encryption!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you care that the data are encrypted when transferred over a network you need to have a look at the transferred data at the network level. There are tools for this like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) which are able to both capture data and to analyze the data.

If this tool is properly used and your connection properly done you should see that your application establishes a TLS connection to the server. You can get security details of this connection like TLS protocol version and cipher by looking at the TLS handshake, but this requires at least some understanding of how TLS works.

You could also have a look at the transferred application data and assume that these are encrypted since you don't find any plain data in it. But this assumption by its own is wrong: both encrypted and compressed data look similar chaotic. And even if the data are compressed you cannot see just by looking at the encrypted data if the encryption is actually strong enough. In other words: you need to rely on the known good properties of the TLS protocol, of the chosen cipher and of the assumption that both peers actually speak proper TLS and do not fake something which just looks like this, in order to be sufficiently sure that the data are securely encrypted.

Answer (score 3):

[Steffen Ullrich's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/218382/163495) correctly describes how you can check if a communication was encrypted or not.

However, you have another option to ensure that TLS communication is indeed encrypted. First of all, I am going to assume that you control the client, and that you will be acting in good faith (aka. not attempt to compromise yourself).

TLS works by having both the client announce the ciphers they support. The server then either responds with a cipher from that list, or in case the server supports none of them, an error message.

What this means is that you, as the client, can send a list of secure ciphers you would like to use, and expect the server to pick one of those it supports. Once the handshake has succeeded, your client will use that cipher for all following communication, and you can be certain that the encryption will happen exactly as specified. Otherwise, the server would not be able to communicate with the client.

## Can TLS ever be not encrypted?

Glad that you asked! **Yes, TLS does not require encryption!** For instance, the ciphersuite `TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA` do not include any encryption at all. This means that the transported payload has no confidentiality whatsoever.

This was mainly used for when the payload was already encrypted, so encrypting it twice (once in the application layer, once on the transport layer), would not be a good idea. At least, that was the idea behind it.